# Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxExcepti

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

Can someone please help me with my probelm.
When i execute the below cypher query im getting exception as in the Title:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///MNK/device.csv" AS line
MATCH (rSeq:Sequence{key:"runId_seq"})
OPTIONAL MATCH (l:Location{siteGaid:line.location_key}) WHERE NOT l:Model 
WITH count(l) as i, line.location_key as key,line.location_key as sourceobjectId,
timestamp() as createdate,rSeq.runId as runId
CALL apoc.do.when(
     i = 0,
    'CREATE (a:locationServiceMigrationError   
    {errorCode: "missing_location",   
    errorDescription: "unable to find Location by its key",  
    matchingObjectKey: key,  
    srcObjectId: sourceobjectId,
    type:"Location",
    srcObjectName: "location_key",
    sourceFileName: "device.csv",
    scriptName:"device.cql",
    createdDate:createdate,
    runId:runId
    }) RETURN a AS node',
'RETURN 0 AS result',
    {key:key,
    sourceobjectId:sourceobjectId,
    createdate:createdate}
) YIELD value
RETURN count(value);
```

...Getting Error message like below

Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.do.when`: Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.internal.v3_5.util.SyntaxException: Variable `runId` not defined (line 11, column 11 (offset: 463))

...When i tried changing the 1st line with different file name as below then it is going fine.
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///MNK/location_coordinate_service.csv" AS line

.. Im not able to understand what exactly the issue is .

Answer (score 0):

`runId` has to be passed into the parameter list too,

```
...,
{
key:key,
sourceobjectId:sourceobjectId,
createdate:createdate,
runId: runId
}
```